# Android: Dynamically set text in Navgation Drawer error

Tags: android

I am trying to set Text in navigation drawer through main class after user successfully logs in. It is working fine when I use the below code:

```
 if(LoggedFlag==1) {
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home_logged);

    }
    else{
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);
    }

    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Home.this, AddTrek.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);

    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();


    NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
    /*View hd = navigationView.inflateHeaderView(R.layout.nav_header_home);
    tvNavName = (TextView)hd.findViewById(R.id.tv_nav_name);
    tvNavName.setText("hello");*/
```

But when I uncomment the setText part and run, I get two drawers one with the text that is set in xml file, and other with the text "hello".
what changes do I have to make here to get only one drawer with the text that I pass through main class.

Comment: If you are comment `Programatically` and set as an `xml` then how is it possible to display two different `TextView`.

Comment: Use the `getHeaderView()` method, and `findViewById()`, to find the `TextView` inflated from the layout XML, instead of inflating a second header. Alternatively, remove the one in the XML, and just use the one you're inflating there.

Comment: I have mentioned below that "when I uncomment ....".

Comment: @Mike..thanks it works that way..